# What are the benefits of using IronPython over IronRuby or F#?

Tags: f#, ironpython, ironruby

Well aware that DLR is here!! I have recently reading up on all of these and was wondering if there were any specific benefits of using one language over another?

For example performance benefits! and available functionality through standard libaries!!

Comment: F# is not a dynamic language and is not based on DLR.

Comment: Yes strictly it does not implement all dynamic features. http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/faq.aspx#IsItDynamic

So yes you could not compare F# with ironruby or ironpython.

Comment: Which language/technology is best for the job always depends on what you actually want to do.

Comment: Definitely agree with that last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "depends".

**F#** is great if you need to functional programming is used extensively by Academics that need its pure computing power to get something done.

**IronPython** and **IronRuby** is great for being able to create applications that run on the CLR because they give you the .NET goodness with the speed of writing Python or Ruby. I don't think that any of these is more preferable to another without it being in a proper context

Comment: My main focus really is for web apps and system admin tools!! With Django my feelings would be that IronPython would be more useful for a .net developer?

Comment: as Django is a python project IronPython would be the only choice for .NET

Comment: You may want to check out http://ndjango.org, it's an django port to .NET using F#.

Comment: Thanks for that will have a look :)

Comment: Functional programming has left the academics status long ago. SQL, XSLT + XPath, Haskell, LISP and now LINQ and F# are all functional languages or technologies that have found their way into typical business scenarios, most notably data processing and semantic web scenarios.

Comment: i am not saying its just for academics, I just said they use it extensively. F# is a First Class language in .NET as of VS2010 so will definitely be used a lot more